# javascript array/object issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to push elements onto an array.

**EDIT**

```
 task.prototype.goTest=function(){

     for(a = 0; a < test.length; a++) {
        if(this.testnumber != test[a].number) {

            //it will only loop 8 times under conditional statement            
            group = {
                title: test[a].Title,
                ID: test[a].ID,
                contents: []
            };

            this.company.push(group);
            this.testnumber = test.number[a];
        }
        //outside of if conditional statement.. it will loop 15 times
        //i want every test[a].conetents get pushed to group.contents array. 
        //this.company is the final variable I need for this function...    

        group.contents.push(test[a].contents);
    }
    console.log(this.company);
}
```

However, when I do

```
console.log(this.company);
```

I see 8 elmements with only 1 element in each `group.contents` array.  The ideal situation is to have 8 elements with 2 to 3 elements in the `group.contents` array.

this refers to the object in the function.
Any idea how to solve my issue?

Comment: When you do `console.log` where?  What is `this`?  We need more info if we're going to be able to help.  Some sample data would be good too.

Comment: I think your mind has a very hard algorithm to solve problems. Lets talk about the needs, not your code cause as far as I see it's so complicated for doing a simple thing.

Comment: @MohammadGoudarzi I need to have every elements in my group.content array and only want 8 elements of group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a new `group`  object each loop, so the reference to `group.contents` is only the current one, it does *not* reference the previously created `group` objects.

So, each time you call `group.contents.push`, you are only pushing onto the object created in that loop iteration.